# Aggregate a value with linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following code:

```
XElement file = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(FileData));;
var file_data = (
    from hl in imported_file.Descendants("HEADER")
        select new

      {
          Year = ((string)hl.Element("Year")),
          Customer= ((string)hl.Element("Customer")),
           PurchasedItem = (string)hl.Element("PurchasedItem"),

      }).Distinct().GroupBy(a => new { a.Year, a.Customer })
```

I would like to select a collection of  Year, Customer and comma separated list of purchased item bound to each grouped year/Customer key.

XML sample

```
<root>
    <Header>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Customer>Jani</Customer>
    <PurchasedItem>item1</PurchasedItem>
    </Header>

    <Header>
    <Year>2002</Year>
    <Customer >Paul</Customer>
    <PurchasedItem>item1</PurchasedItem>
    </Header>

    <Header>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Customer>Jani</Customer>
    <PurchasedItem >item2</PurchasedItem>
    </Header>

    <Header>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Customer >Jani</Customer>
    <PurchasedItem  >item1</PurchasedItem>
    </Header>

    <Header>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Customer >Jani</Customer>
    <PurchasedItem  >item3</PurchasedItem>
    </Header>
</root>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Please see updated question above with a sample xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - xml you've posted was invalid (missed root element, incorrect closing tags and so on). I've corrected it.

Concerning you goal. It can be achieved something like:

```
var result = file.Descendants("Header").Select(hl => new
{
    Year = ((string) hl.Element("Year")),
    Customer = ((string) hl.Element("Customer")),
    PurchasedItem = (string) hl.Element("PurchasedItem")
})
.Distinct()
.GroupBy(a => new {a.Year, a.Customer})
.Select(r => new
{
    Year = r.Key.Year,
    Customer = r.Key.Customer,
    Items = String.Join(", ", r.Select(x => x.PurchasedItem))
});
```

Key idea - after you've grouped your data using `GroupBy` - just add some selector and rearrange your result as needed.

Comment: True, i did miss the root. Many thanks again for your time.